# problems with cookies with express-session node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, express-session, react-fullstack

i deploy my api in fl0 and use the free url from fl0 and deploy my frontend in vercel, the problem is that cookies doesnt save in the client,

my configuration of express-session is:

`const store = connectMongo.create({`
`mongoUrl: process.env.MONGODB_ACCESS_STRING,`
`ttl: 24 * 60 * 60 * 10000`
`})`

`export const sessions = session({`

`store,`

`secret: process.env.SECRET_COOKIE_KEY,`

`resave: false,`

`saveUninitialized: false,`

`cookie: {`

`secure: true ,`

`httpOnly: true,`

`domain: 'xxx-xxxx-xxx.vercel.app',`

`sameSite: 'none',`
`}`
`})`

this is the app configuration of express-session, cors and passport

`const app = express()`

`app.use(cors({`
``` origin: '``https://xxx-xxxx-xxx.vercel.app``', ```
`credentials: true,`
`}));`

`app.use(express.json())`

`app.use(sessions)`

`app.use(passportInitialize)`

`app.use(passportSession)`

and the fetch from client:

`` const res = await fetch(${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL}/Login`, ``

`{`
`method: 'POST',`

`credentials:'include',`

`headers: {`
`'Content-Type': 'application/json'`
`},`

`body: JSON.stringify({`
`email: email,`
`password: password,`
`})`

```
  })
```

can somebody helpme? in the localhost everything work but in deploy the cookies fail, everything else work good

i think that i have configuration wrong but i don't know